# Make Spark Streaming start Spark Batch jobs

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to implement a lambda architecture from Spark, Kafka and HBase. Although definitely possible to change it if there is an easier option, my current idea consists of a streaming job taking stuff from Kafka, storing them to HBase and then performing the calculations on the data, all while also calculating the earliest timestamp of the production of the data(that timestamp is the key for each message in Kafka). Upon calculating the timestamp it needs to check if a batch job is running and if not it needs to start a new batch job with the upper interval being that timestamp. I am not sure how the streaming job can control and start the batch job. Any ideas?

Here's a code with some comments on what stuff is needed and some background info:

```
    final String lowBoundary = args[0];
    final String highBoundary = args[1];

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setMaster("spark://dissertation:7077")
            .setAppName("LambdaStream");
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(2));

    ssc.checkpoint("hdfs://localhost:9000/spark");

    HashSet<String> topicSet = new HashSet<String>();
    topicSet.add("generator");

    HashMap<String, String> kafkaMap = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaMap.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");

    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> stream = KafkaUtils
            .createDirectStream(ssc, String.class, String.class,
                    StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaMap, topicSet);

    // Data is generated from TPC-H, so every row, or every Kafka message has the data's timestamp as key
    // and all the attributes separated by |
    JavaPairDStream<String, String[]> tuples = stream
            .mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String, String>, String, String[]>() {

                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, String[]> call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple) {

                    String[] split = tuple._2.split(Pattern.quote("|"));

                    return new Tuple2<String, String[]>(tuple._1, split);
                }
            });

    // I'll omit the saving to HBase code as it's too long and useless

    JavaDStream<Integer> filterAndCount = tuples.filter(new Function<Tuple2<String, String[]>, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean call(Tuple2<String, String[]> tuple) {
            if (Long.parseLong(tuple._2[0]) > Long.parseLong(lowBoundary)
                    && Long.parseLong(tuple._2[0]) < Long.parseLong(highBoundary)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }).map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String[]>, Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer call(Tuple2<String, String[]> tuple) throws Exception {
            return tuple._2[15].split(" ").length;
        }
    }).reduce(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) throws Exception {
            return a + b;
        }
    });

    // The lowest timestamp is used to pe provided as the higher boundary for the batch job and is
    // also going to be used as the key for the HBase table in which the result from this microbatch is stored
    JavaDStream<Long> lowestTimestamp = stream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, Long>() {

        @Override
        public Long call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple) throws Exception {
            return Long.parseLong(tuple._1);
        }

    }).reduce(new Function2<Long, Long, Long>() {

        @Override
        public Long call(Long a, Long b) throws Exception {
            if (a > b) {
                return b;
            } else {
                return a;
            }
        }

    });
    // After calculation of the smallest timestamp I need to check if batch is over and if so start it with a scan limited to the
    // minimum timestamp provided by this.
```

EDIT: Added code as requested

Comment: That's not really how spark streaming works. The principal is that you have a constant stream of RDDs being read from your source, in this case Kafka. There's no need to manually trigger a read.

Comment: How do I achieve a lambda architecture then? I need something that is resilient to be tracking the spark job's status constantly and upon finishing it needs to restart it with parameters gotten from the stream job's latest output. The main issue is the resiliency... Actually I have absolutely no idea on how to restart the job in any way, nobody provides info on that and I have no details on what Spark does with a job after it's submitted

Comment: *I need something that is resilient to be tracking the spark job's status constantly and upon finishing it needs to restart it with parameters gotten from the stream job's latest output*. Can you post a [mcve] of your problem? I'm not following on the need to restart a job based on latest output parameters.

Comment: Done. Basically the Kafka input has the timestamp of when the producer got the data as the key and a long string of all the other needed data. One small problem is the potential falling behind of some nodes, thus the order of the production of the data being useless, but I'm not sure I can get around that, that's Spark Streaming's disatvantage